"cordova" is not recognised as a cmdlet name
I installed Cordova with this command using npm:
npm install -g cordova

Cordova is now installed, the files and the folder appear in %appdata%/npm and %appdata%/npm/node_modules
but whenever I try to execute any Cordova command through the VS Code terminal it gives an error that says:

"cordova" is not recognised as cmdlet name

When I execute commands through PowerShell it still gives and error but it's slightly different and it says:

"cordova" is not recognised as internal command

I tried reinstalling cordova and reinitializing NPM, nothing worked.

Add the install location of cordova to the PATH variable.  E.g.: %appdata%/npm/node_modules/.bin/

The solution was to add "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin" path in the PATH system variable.

Does the rest of the npm packages work for you?
If you don't add a global variable to the computer as they wrote you in the comment
If so:
Try closing and reopening PowerShell or cmd
If it still doesn't help, try restarting the computer. If it still doesn't help, update here.
